# rutas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rutas

estoy probando laravel y me encuentro frente a este inconveniente..

en mi archivo web.php tengo:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    
/*    $images = Image::all();
    foreach($images as $image){
        echo $image->image_path."<br>";
        echo $image->description."<br>";
        echo $image->user->name." ".$image->user->surname;
        if(count($image->likes)>=1){
            echo "<br>likes: ".count($image->likes);
        }

        if(count($image->comments)>=1){
            echo "<h4>Comentarios</h4>";
            foreach($image->comments as $comment){
                echo $comment->user->name." ".$image->user->surname.": ".$comment->content."<br>";
            }
        }

        echo "<hr>";
    }*/

    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Una vez que me registro en la pagina quiero que me redireccione a la ruta mencionada anteriormente.. pero me tira error y no se si es de sintaxis o de alguna inconsistencia

Probe de dos formas

```
protected $redirectTo =RouteServiceProvider::'/';
protected $redirectTo =RouteServiceProvider::/;
```

El error era 404 not found

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error obtenido?

Comment: Esta sintaxis: **`RouteServiceProvider::/;`** no es válida, debe ser de esta forma: **RouteServiceProvider::ALGUNA_CONSTANTE;** puesto que en tu *service provider* `HOME` es la constante cuyo string usas para hacer la redirección

Answer (score 1):

creo que descubri como era, debia dirigirme a `app\Providers\RouteServiceProviders.php`
y alli se encuentra la linea `public const HOME = '/home';`
Simplemente cambie el `/home` por `/`

Por si a alguien le sirve..

Comment: Ahi lo agregue en la pregunta!